# Which skills are exclusive to a class in Dark Heresy?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e

In Dark Heresy your skill choices are determined by your class and rank.  **Which skills (not talents) are unique to only a single class?**  Assume just the core Dark Heresy manual for reference.

To clarify, assume this references the classes as written.  I know it is possible to ask the game master for advancements that are not on your list.

Comment: WIth all due respect, if the answer is a simple matter of checking the book, and it is even known ***which*** part of the book to check, is it a real question..?

Comment: As a matter of fact, putting together a list of career-exclusive skills is quite a tedious work. I suppose OP hopes to see a link to the job already done.

Comment: @JeorMattan That is exactly what I was assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a reference which can answer your question in the Mediafire folder [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?pgcftr65oepfo).  It's the file called "Skills with Errata 5c.pdf" ([direct link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?eterjmjytmn)).

It lists what skills each class gets and when in tabular form, so it should be easy to tell which skills have only a single entry.

Comment: Exactly the kind of information I was hoping was already put together, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you mean by the rules or in playing. If a pg can find someone that can teach him a skill, he can learn (paying the appropriate xp, expecially if it's not in the list of his career)

Comment: Welcome to the site, @lunadir.